# FastLane could not recognize adb on windows 10

Tags: android, fastlane, screen-grab

I'm trying to use fastlane for andrid app and I have this problem in this fastlane command for screengrab:

```
bundle exec fastlane screengrab
```

and Im getting this error while using screengrab:

> [13:42:12]: The `adb` command could not be found relative to your
> provided ANDROID_HOME at C:/Users/Ramin/AppData/Local/Android/ Sdk
> [13:42:12]: Please ensure that the Android SDK is installed and the
> platform-tools directory is present
>
> [!] adb command not found

I have seen the same [question](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16075) before. But the problem remains open. Is there any update?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add adb to your path, i.e. via the environment variables on Windows. Then restart the command line and try again.

Comment: I did this. This problem exists with Windows and Linux, and the solution is to change the library.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16075#issuecomment-687767176

Answer (score 0):

This problem exists with Windows and Linux ([issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16075)), and the solution is to change the library.

I did this with the library and its work!!

dir: fastlane/screengrab/lib/screengrab/android_environment.rb

orginal:

```
def find_adb(platform_tools_path) 
   return FastlaneCore::CommandExecutor.which('adb') unless platform_tools_path 
  
   adb_path = File.join(platform_tools_path, 'adb') 
   return executable_command?(adb_path) ? adb_path : nil 
 end
```

modified:

```
 def find_adb(platform_tools_path) 
   return 'adb'
 end
```